# Plotting the Layers of Earth

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, generative-art

I want to generate a picture like below with *Mathematica*. I mean exactly the same thing, except maybe the map depicted on the outer layer. But I don't know where to start from! I would appreciate it if someone gives me some hints as far as possible or gives it a try.

[image: Earth layers]

Comment: You can start giving a look at this link (and the links in it): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57434/plotting-semi-hollow-spheres
and

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a method that uses [constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) to form concentric hollow spheres with a quadrant cut out from the center. First, define four filled objects that we'll use as geometric regions. This gets part way to the layered Earth picture.

```
orb = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1.0];
orb2 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 0.8];
orb3 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 0.6];
cube = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 1}]; (* used to remove a quadrant *)
```

Note that `Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 1}]` removes a front-facing quadrant, which simplifies the the following images, but `Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]` works equally well.

Step 1: Use `RegionDifference` to remove a quadrant from the largest sphere.

```
r1 = RegionDifference[
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[orb, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005], 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cube]]
```

[image: sphere with quadrant removed]

Step 2: Next, remove the next smaller sphere from the center of region `r1`.

```
r2 = RegionDifference[r1, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[orb2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005]]
```

[image: hollow sphere with cutout]

Step 3: Convert the region `r2` to graphics and color it.

```
shell1 = RegionPlot3D[r2, PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: colorized red shell]

Repeat these 3 steps for each smaller shell. Here's a smaller, green-colored shell that fits inside `shell1`.

```
r3 = RegionDifference[
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[orb2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005], 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cube]];
r4 = RegionDifference[r3, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[orb3, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005]];
shell2 = RegionPlot3D[r4, PlotStyle -> Green, Boxed -> False];
```

Combine the shells with a solid sphere in the center.

```
Show[shell1, shell2, 
 RegionPlot3D[orb3, PlotStyle -> Yellow, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: result]

To make the Earth layers, combine 5 colored shells with a solid sphere to fill the center.

**Update:**

For convenience (while also solving the jagged edge problem), combine the steps into a function with parameters for shell outer- and inner-radius, and color:

```
shell[r1_, r2_, c_] := Module[{ra, rb},
   ra = RegionDifference[
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005], BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cube]];
   rb = RegionDifference[ra, 
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r2], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005]];
   RegionPlot3D[rb, PlotStyle -> c, Boxed -> False]
   ];
```

Combine multiple shells, and use `Show` as before.

```
shells = {shell[1, .95, Brown], shell[.95, .85, Lighter[Green]] (*, ... *)};
Show[Sequence[shells], (* innermost sphere here *)]
```

Comment: That's awesome. You saved me! :) Thank you very much. (+1) and accepted.

Comment: Hi again, can you kindly take look at my answer below. I am having an issue with smoothing the the final result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Initially, I found similar problems getting smooth edges. My solution, above, was to use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` before `RegionDifference`. The expression became unwieldy so I broke it into steps, and that solved the edge problem.

Comment: Another problem I found with combined expressions (e.g., combining `RegionDifference` and `RegionUnion`) was a `BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because the edges` error. The separate steps eliminated that (and similar) errors.

Comment: I added a function as an example of a simple way to create shells. See **Update**.

Comment: Wonderful solution. +1 for getting the smooth edges!

Comment: How much time did it take for you to get an output for `r2`? I have not been able to get an output for it! Mathematica just doesn't stop running! My Mathematica version is 11.2 on Windows 7 with a 1050 GTX graphic card and 7700HQ CPU.

Comment: I found average of 7.5 seconds over 10 runs - version 11.3 on Mac OS x86-64. Try changing `MaxCellMeasure` to a larger value.

Comment: I tried that but the output quality becomes so poor.

Comment: I updated my Mathematical from 11.2 to 11.3 and every works fine as you told. :)

Answer (score 11):

This is not meant to belittle H.R.'s efforts.

I just observed that `ContourPlot3D` with a suitable `RegionFunction` does a much better job with respect to both performance and quality than `RegionPlot3D`.

Moreover, once we have the (cut out) shell of the unit sphere, we may use it multiple times to construct the thickened shells. We can also compute quadrilateral polygons from the polygons of the spherical shell by detecting its boundary edges (edges that have only one polygon next to it).

Finally, many of the actual shells cannot be seen in the final plot, so leaving them aways saves us to render 80% of the polygons.

First, we need some preparation.

```
Module[{r, shellplot, bndedges, edges, plist},
   r = 1.1;
   shellplot = ContourPlot3D[
     x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,
     {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
     RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0),
     Mesh -> None,
     PlotPoints -> 50,
     MaxRecursion -> 2
     ];
   gc = Cases[shellplot, _GraphicsComplex, All][[1]];
   pts = gc[[1]];
   polygons = Join @@ Cases[gc, x : Polygon[y_] :> y, All];
   (* extracting edges, packing for more efficiency *)
   edges = Developer`ToPackedArray[Sort /@ Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ polygons)];
   bndedges = GroupBy[Tally[edges], Last -> First][1];
   plist = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]]];
   (* correcting some roughness at the cut boundary *)
   pts[[plist]] = bndpts = Threshold[pts[[plist]], 0.01];
   (* renumbering the edge indices *)
   bndedges = Partition[
     Lookup[
      AssociationThread[plist -> Range[Length[plist]]], 
      Flatten[bndedges]
      ], 
     2
     ];
   quads = Join[bndedges, Transpose[Transpose[bndedges + Length[plist]][[{2, 1}]]], 2];
   ];

Shell2[a_, b_, Color_, innerQ_, outerQ_] :=
 {
  EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Darker@Color], Specularity[White, 30],
  GraphicsComplex[Join[a  bndpts, b bndpts], Polygon[quads]],
  If[innerQ,
   GraphicsComplex[a pts, Polygon[polygons], Sequence @@ gc[[3 ;;]]],
   Nothing
   ],
  If[outerQ,
   GraphicsComplex[b pts, Polygon[polygons], Sequence @@ gc[[3 ;;]]],
   Nothing
   ]
  }
```

Now let's actually create the geometries...

```
MyColors = <|
   "Brown" -> RGBColor[0.76, 0.41, 0],
   "Yellow" -> RGBColor[0.93, 1, 0.22],
   "Orange" -> RGBColor[1, 0.75, 0],
   "Green" -> RGBColor[0.4, 0.86, 0],
   "Red" -> RGBColor[1, 0.45, 0.39],
   "Blue" -> RGBColor[0.1, 0.78, 1]
   |>;

Radius = {0.2, 0.35, 0.6, 0.85, 0.95, 1.05, 1.1};

S = ParallelTable[
     Shell2[Radius[[i]], Radius[[i + 1]], MyColors[[i]], i == 1, 
      i == 6],
     {i, 1, 6}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.227411

... and plot them.

```
Graphics3D[S, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

We can see that we cheat the beholder by plotting all but the last "shells":

```
Graphics3D[S[[1 ;; -2]], Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I really appreciate your contribution. :)

Comment: The same idea was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486).

Answer (score 9):

This is an answer motivated by that given by creidhne. Here, I use a slightly different function for producing the shell which is more compact and has the advantage of giving a totally smooth output. As you may notice the triangular mesh over surfaces in the outputs of creidhne is obvious. Furthermore, as the number of layers increases and you may want to get an output with high quality then the run time increases so much. For this reason, I employed a parallel computing approach to reduce the run time. Here the variable `n` is the number of plot points in each direction and by increasing this number the quality of the output will be increased. The default value of `n` in the below code is `50` which produces a poor output. Try for example `n=300` to get a high quality output like below. The run time for `n=300` in Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10 64bit with a 7700HQ intel CPU is about `5.6` minutes so be patient.

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
StartTime = AbsoluteTime[];
MyBlue = RGBColor[0.1, 0.78, 1];
MyBrown = RGBColor[0.76, 0.41, 0];
MyGreen = RGBColor[0.4, 0.86, 0];
MyOrange = RGBColor[1, 0.75, 0];
MyYellow = RGBColor[0.93, 1, 0.22];
MyRed = RGBColor[1, 0.45, 0.39];
n = 50;
Shell[a_, b_, Color_] := RegionPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= b^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= a^2 && 
   \[Not] (x >= 0 && y <= 0 && z >= 0), 
   {x, -b, b}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -b, b}, 
   PlotPoints -> n, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Color, 
   Opacity[1]], Mesh -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
R1 = 0.2;
R2 = 0.35;
R3 = 0.6;
R4 = 0.85;
R5 = 0.95;
R6 = 1.05;
R7 = 1.1;
Radius = {R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7};
MyColors = {MyBrown, MyYellow, MyOrange, MyGreen, MyRed, MyBlue}
SetSharedVariable[S]
S = {};
ParallelDo[
AppendTo[S, Shell[Radius[[i]], Radius[[i + 1]], MyColors[[i]]]], 
{i,1, 6}];
Fig = Show[S, ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {0.75, -1, 0.75}]
EndTime = AbsoluteTime[];
RunTime = EndTime - StartTime
RunTime/60
```

Comment: Nice! Some hints: 1.) In general, it is a good idea to avoid `AppendTo`, in particular when runnings things in parallel (not severe here since `AppendTo` is called only few times). You can simply use `S = ParallelTable[
   Shell[Radius[[i]], Radius[[i + 1]], MyColors[[i]]], {i, 1, 6}];` instead. 2.) Setting `Lighting -> "Neutral"` in `RegionPlot3D` produces somewhat more controllable colors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Thank you Henrik. :)

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Answer (score 7):

A "lazy" method to do this is to use `SliceDensityPlot3D[]` with a custom color function, similar to what was done for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157744):

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
              RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 11/10], 
                               ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}},
                                               {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} 11/10]], 
              MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.02}, Method -> "RegionPlot3D"];

rad = {0.2, 0.35, 0.6, 0.85, 0.95, 1.05, 1.1};

With[{blue = RGBColor[0.1, 0.78, 1], brown = RGBColor[0.76, 0.41, 0], 
      green = RGBColor[0.4, 0.86, 0], orange = RGBColor[1, 0.75, 0], 
      yellow = RGBColor[0.93, 1, 0.22], red = RGBColor[1, 0.45, 0.39]},
     With[{cl = Transpose[{ArrayPad[Riffle[#, #] &[Rescale[Prepend[Rest[rad], 0]]], -1], 
                           Riffle[#, #] &[{brown, yellow, orange, green, red, blue}]}]},
          myCF = Blend[cl, #] &]];

Show[SliceDensityPlot3D[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], reg,
                        {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, {z, -1.1, 1.1},
                        Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> myCF, 
                        PlotPoints -> 245],
     Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.76, 0.41, 0], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, rad[[1]]]}]]
```

[image: layers of a sphere]

This is "lazy" in the sense of needing only minimal programming effort, but the price to pay is that one needs a relatively large `PlotPoints` setting in `SliceDensityPlot3D[]` to get the colors to come out properly.